# Handlebars active TAB

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I have a simple pagination. What I want to do is adding class "active" to active tab (I am on page 8 so button 8 has "active" class)
But it still won't work.
I tried two things but both unsuccessful.

First this:

```
{{#each pagination}}
  {{#if pagHelper}}
    <a>{{this.number}}</a>
  {{else}}
    <li class="paginator-item {{#is this.number current}}active{{/is}}">
      <a href="{{this.href}}" class="paginator-itemLink" onclick="getHref(this)">{{this.number}}</a>
    </li>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Second like this:

```
{{#is this.number current}}{}
  {{#each pagination}}
  {{#if pagHelper}}
    <a>{{this.number}}</a>
  {{else}}
    <li class="paginator-item ">
        <a href="{{this.href}}" class="paginator-itemLink ACTIVE" onclick="getHref(this)">{{this.number}}</a>
    </li>
    {{/if}}
      {{/each}}
    {{else}}
      {{#each pagination}}
    {{#if pagHelper}}
      <a>{{this.number}}</a>
    {{else}}
      <li class="paginator-item ">
        <a href="{{this.href}}" class="paginator-itemLink" onclick="getHref(this)">{{this.number}}</a>
      </li>
    {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
    {{/is}}
```

Basically, I am comparing the current page number and the page number of the button. I tried to log both "current" and "this number" and both gave me correct value. The problem is that when I use "current" in "each" loop it gives me nothing. I will be thankfull for any idea.

Comment: ou wou actually i found answer fast after question i just needed to add "../" to current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add `../` to `current`

```
{{#is this.number current}}active{{/is}}
```

to

```
{{#is this.number ../current}}active{{/is}}
```